Resume URLSession download data
We have a requirement where we want to download data from server, and also provide option to resume the download if it fails for some reason (Network issue etc..). We are using urlSession.downloadTask(with: request) to perform our downloads which is working fine.
We have also implemented the required delegate methods of URLSessionTaskDelegate which is required to save resume data.
public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                           task: URLSessionTask,
                           didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        guard let error = error else {
            // Handle success case.
            return
        }

        let userInfo = (error as NSError).userInfo

        if let resumeData = userInfo[NSURLSessionDownloadTaskResumeData] as? Data,
           let failedUrl = userInfo[NSURLErrorKey] as? String{
            downloadCompletion?(DataContentModel(resumeData: resumeData, url: failedUrl))
        }
    }

For testing purpose, I tried disconnecting wifi connection when download is in progress, and after few seconds the call went to the delegate function, but the userInfo dict didn't had the required key NSURLSessionDownloadTaskResumeData . Now, I understand that apple document says that if key dosen't exist then data can't be resumed, but how can we determine

what kind of download is resumable?

Do we need any configuration at server end, or do we need to read some other key? Can someone please help on this. Thanks in advance.

Did you read the documentation? All the conditions for a download to be resumable are listed there.

@Sweeper I checked it, but thought it's only applicable when we call cancel closure my bad. So, those conditions are valid even for delegate function.

"The server provides either the ETag or Last-Modified header (or both) in its response" and "The server supports byte-range requests" from the doc previously linked: Is that the case from your server?

Also, must be a GET request (no POST), and probably can't be in an ephemeral session.  (I've never tried, but it seems like it is likely to fail, because ephemeral sessions shouldn't persist anything to disk, including the partially downloaded data.).

But yeah, odds are you're using Apache and you haven't turned on ETag support in the server config file.

You can use cancel(byProducingResumeData:) to cancel a download task and retrieve the resume data. This data can then be used with the downloadTask(withResumeData:) function to resume the download if possible.
According to Apple documentation, it can resume if the following conditions are met:

A download can be resumed only if the following conditions are met:
The resource has not changed since you first requested it
The task is an HTTP or HTTPS GET request
The server provides either the ETag or Last-Modified header (or both)
in its response
The server supports byte-range requests
The temporary file hasn’t been deleted by the system in response to
disk space pressure

Also, you can get the resume data when the following condition occurs in the didCompleteWithError function::

if (error.userInfo[NSURLErrorBackgroundTaskCancelledReasonKey] as? NSNumber)?.intValue == NSURLErrorCancelledReasonUserForceQuitApplication ||
(error.userInfo[NSURLErrorBackgroundTaskCancelledReasonKey] as? NSNumber)?.intValue == NSURLErrorCancelledReasonBackgroundUpdatesDisabled {

 let resumeData = nsError.userInfo[NSURLSessionDownloadTaskResumeData] as? Data

//Do what you want

}



Not sure why this is modded down.  It appears to be the correct answer.  If any of those conditions aren't met, you won't get resume data, and if they're all met, you should.

Things to add would be links to turning on ETag support on Apache.  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#FileETag
